# Get direct reports ID in LDAP

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I am using the LDAP for retrieving the hierarchy in my organisation. Under the property **directreports** I am getting all the names of the employees reporting under me. But I want to get their unique Identification (may be some employee id). How can I do that?

Comment: Are you getting their full names or the unique user names? Please check the exact property of LDAP which matches with the name. It could be name or givenname or something like that

Comment: I am getting common names for the direct reports.

Comment: So in case two person have same name how is it displayed?

Comment: Example- Gangopadhyay, Prateek and Gangopadhyay, Prateek1. The names get changed. In some cases the first name in some cases the second and I have not found out any any scenario to distinguish between how they are given.

Comment: What I can plan to do is I can recall the LDAP passing the names as parameter and populate the id for a particular associate. And to this recursively for the subordinates of the associate.

Comment: You can search through the UserPrincipal. I have posted a working code as answer. Please check.

Comment: Oh yes. I saw the code. Network issue in my mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

Add `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` references in your project and import the namespaces.

```
var listOfDirectReportsNames = // Get the list of all the directreports user names and store in list- List<string>();

var pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
foreach (string name in listOfDirectReportsNames)
{
    var up = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(pc);
    up.Name = name; //to test this, pass the exact LDAP Name/DisplayName/GivenName of any user
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher(up);
    var res = searcher.FindOne();
    string empID = ((System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal)res).EmployeeId;//here you will get employee ID
    up.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: There is another alternative approach. The common names are unique for our organisation. So we have a flexibility to search by a parameter "cn" which stands for common name. This gives you the employee id for a particular profile. And use that employee id to recursively call the process of fetching data and make your organisation hierarchy ready as you want.Before going through this alternative approach please make sure that the common names are unique for each employee.